# How to download Arch Linux from a mirror

Tags: arch-linux, mirror

I went to https://www.archlinux.org/download/ then I clicked on a mirror site and a site popped up, but this just seems to be a filesystem. How do I download from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find some mirror geographically near to you. Let's pretend you are French, so it could be https://mirror.thekinrar.fr/archlinux/iso/2018.05.01/

You'll find remote files such as [archlinux-2018.05.01-x86_64.iso](https://mirror.thekinrar.fr/archlinux/iso/2018.05.01/archlinux-2018.05.01-x86_64.iso)

Download that [ISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) with a good enough HTTP client, preferably on the command line. If you use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), it would be

```
wget https://mirror.thekinrar.fr/archlinux/iso/2018.05.01/archlinux-2018.05.01-x86_64.iso
```

If you don't understand what I mean, read more about the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol. You need to use some [HTTP `GET` request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). Choose the appropriate HTTP client capable of doing that correctly.

You could download the checksum files, like `md5sums.txt` to be able to check that your downloaded image was not corrupted during the download.

Then burn that ISO image into a CDROM or an USB key (how to do that might depend upon your current operating system, perhaps you might use [Nero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero_Burning_ROM) on Windows, which I don't know).

Read [Getting and Installing Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Category:Getting_and_installing_Arch).